# Cannot connect HoloLens 2 to 5GHz Mobile Hotspot

Tags: windows-10, wifi, hololens, hotspot

Recently while trying out Holographic Remoting I have noticed that the HoloLens 2 will not connect to a 5GHz mobile hotspot provided by my computer. Due to the HoloLens' onboard 802.11ac WLAN chip, I would expect this to work. My computer is capable of 802.11ac and is configured to do so in the device manager.

Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows Holographic version 2004 is installed.

Steps for reproduction:

1. Turn on WLAN Hotspot in Windows 10 computer (developer mode is activated).
2. Select 5GHz as band from the dropdown list.
3. Open the list of networks in the HoloLens network settings. The hotspot does not appear in the list of available networks.

If I change the band to 2.4GHz in the hotspot settings and refresh the list in the HoloLens, the network appears. In addition, a 5GHz network will also appear when the Hololens is connected to a Netgear R6120 WLAN AC1200 router.

Has anyone experienced this same behavior when using the Windows Mobile Hotspot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mihai at Microsoft Support, I have a solution to this issue:

Disable the WIFI on HoloLens, then enable the 5ghz Hot-spot on the laptop, then enable the WIFI on HoloLens, the hotspot will be detected and you can connect successfully.

In my case, the HoloLens was already connected to another network. As such I needed to disconnect before the computer's hotspot would appear in the network list.

Answer (score 2):

What we want to point out is that the frequency range of Wi-Fi is not user configurable and depends on the country of use. In the US Wi-Fi uses both 2.4 GHz (1-11) channels and 5 GHz (36-64, 100-165) channels. So,  it is recommended to first try to change the channel of your hotspot to fall under the usable range. If it's still not working after fix the channel, please contact the after-sales department of Microsoft.

More information please see:[Frequently asked HoloLens (1st gen) Security Questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens1-faq-security)

Comment: It is not possible to configure the channels used by the Windows 10 Mobile Hotspot, only the preferred bandwidth. A physical router on the other hand allows me to change channels (36-64), and as such, it works as expected. But that is not what I want!

Comment: Since this issue involves HoloLens hardware, it is recommended you to open a support ticket  through this link: http://aka.ms/hololenssupport so that we can diagnose it deeper for you.